# My Minecraft library disappeared!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built a library underground, and just a few day ago I went there and 90% of the bookshelves (wood) was gone. My friend said that it was an enderman! Can that be true? How can I protect against it?

Comment: Is there lava near your library?

Comment: Were you playing on a server? you most likely got griefed.

Answer (score 9):

Enderman can't move wooden blocks or bookcases assuming  you're on the latest version. They have a [limited block set](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman#Moving_blocks). IF you want to protect against Endermen keep the surrounding area bright, but they have a habit of teleporting into bright areas. But as I said, Endermen wouldn't do this.

As noted elsewhere, it's possible lava burned stuff up; if you hear lava inside the library, dig out 2 blocks in everyway from the inside wall of the library and lava shouldn't be able to reach your wodden walls.

If you're playing on a server I'd suspect another player and/or a fire that got out of hand.

Comment: I'd say just "and", if it's a server...

Comment: If it's *deep* underground, my money is on lava-sparked fire. Just listen for the lava bubbling sound.

Comment: Good point. I encountered a stronghold library with lava flowing through it once...

Comment: I had lava, I never thought that that would ever happen thanks for the help!

Comment: @Lidia lava's burning/damage physics are still sort of weird I believe. Remember you can mark an answer as accepted with the checkmark at the side of the answer